# Apache Solrのsolrconfig.xmlの設定項目一覧を知る方法はありませんか？

Tags: solr

Apache Solrという検索エンジンがあります。
この検索エンジンでは、いくつかの設定ファイルがあり、
例えばsolrconfig.xmlというファイルを利用します。

しかしこのsolrconfig.xmlのリファレンスとして提供されている物は
実際にはリファレンスというよりは、ユーザマニュアルのような形式のものになっており、
(xmlの具体的なノードの名前や、プロパティの名前のレベルで)"具体的にどんな設定値を書き込めるのか" を集めづらいです。

たとえば
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/configuring-solrconfig-xml.html
から調べると

> We’ve covered the options in the following sections:

のような記述があり、この下に各大きな枠での設定項目へのリンクが並ぶため、一覧性がありそうに見えます。
しかし実際に、この文以下にあるリンクを踏むと、中には細かい解説が並ぶばかりで網羅はされていません。

またこのリンク先の解説では、その設定項目について言及されていない情報が度々あるようです。
たとえば
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/indexconfig-in-solrconfig.html#mergepolicyfactory
では、TieredMergePolicyFactoryに実際に指定できる `maxMergedSegmentMB` などのパラメタが記載されていません。
(詳細はJavaDocを読めとあるのですが、JavaDocにあるのはクラス実装についての情報であって、設定項目とは関係のないメソッドなどが並んでいます)

これらの情報が一覧できる情報源をご存知でしたら、教えていただけないでしょうか。

たとえば

- 実は公式に設定項目を一覧できるリファレンスが存在する
- Solrから設定項目名をプログラム的に抜き出す方法がある
- solrconfig.xml のXMLのスキーマ情報を引っ張る方法
- JavaDocの内容が実は設定項目と1:1に対応しているなどの事情があり、その読み取り方がこうなっている

……などの知見があれば、一番ありがたいです。